# Overriding fluid_styled_content isn't working as expected

Tags: typo3, fluid, fluid-styled-content

Hei guys,

I've been trying really hard to override the templates, partials, and headers of some default content elements from fluid_styled_content. 
For instance, lets say 'Header'.

I also have a data processing class to fetch certain fields from tt_content table to process inside the header.
Anyhow, I can receive this fetched data inside the template. But not in the partials or layouts.
Did anyone ever faced the same?

This was my TS setup :

```
lib.contentElement {
  templateRootPaths {
     200 = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Templates/
  }
  partialRootPaths {
     200 = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Partials/
  }
  layoutRootPaths {
     200 = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Layouts/
  }
}

//custom content element definition

tt_content {
  header < lib.contentElement
  header {
     templateName = Header
     dataProcessing {
        1 = VENDOR\MyExt\DataProcessing\ContentProcessor
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: please give hint about your version of TYPO3 as some things are handled differently in the different versions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's about the order of your typoscript.

in your example you have the code

```
tt_content {
    header < lib.contentElement
    :
```

which copies the `lib.contentElement` object. it copies the object in that state it has in the moment when the [copy operator](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/8.7/Syntax/TypoScriptSyntax/Index.html#object-copying-the-sign) is detected. any following changes will not be included.

If you want to build a *reference*, where you can change the referenced ('copied') object afterwards and all those changes should be active too you need to use the [reference operator](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/8.7/Syntax/TypoScriptSyntax/Index.html#references-the-sign):

```
tt_content {
    header =< lib.contentElement
    :
```